# Ordering a VB dictionary by value, then looping through the ordered values

Tags: vb.net, dictionary, visual-studio-2012

I have a dictionary of (string, integer). I need to order the dictionary by integer first, then use each integer value in a loop.
For instance, the dictionary contains cat 2, dog 1, rat 3...ordered would be dog 1, cat 2, rat 3. Then I would get the first value, 1, perform some functions with it, get the next value 2, perform some functions with it, and so on until the end of the dictionary.

So far I have:

```
Dim ordered = newdictionary.OrderBy(Function(x) x.Value)
   ordered.Select(Function(x) x.Value)
```

What is a good way to accomplish this?

Comment: Dictionaries are unordered.

Comment: Can the dictionary be rebuilt as ordered pairs by value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be what you actually want:

```
For Each value In newdictionary.Values.OrderBy(Function(i) i)
    ' do something with the value '
Next
```

Now you're looping the ordered `int` values of the dictionary

[`Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.Values` Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ekcfxy3x.aspx)

**Edit** according to your comment you want to include the index to check if the next element equals the current:

```
Dim values = newdictionary.Values.
    Select(Function(i, index) New With {.Num = i, .Index = index}).
    OrderBy(Function(x) x.Num)
For Each value In values
    Dim nextElement = values.ElementAtOrDefault(value.Index + 1)
    If nextElement Is Nothing OrElse nextElement.Num <> value.Num Then
        ' next value is different or last element
    Else
        ' next number same 
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Can this be used to compare the chosen value to the next value in the sequence? For example, I'm performing functions with value "1", and if the next value in the dictionary is also "1" do "x", if not do "y".